# Android - How to lock camera resolution on 640 x 480

Tags: android, image, camera, resolution

I want to lock camera resolution to take photos under 640x480 px, can i do that?

This need to be done 'cause photos larger than 640x480 make they exibition very slow, sometimes even crash my app.
If this can't be done, there is some method to resize my picture on SD Card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could resize picture even before saving it to SD card. In code, something like this:

```
Bitmap smallBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBitmap, 640, 480, true);
```

and after resize save it with code I guess you already wrote for saving..

In case you need to supply byte array and not Bitmap for saving you can use:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bMap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos); // setup jpeg quality here
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
```

Hope it helped.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the lowest resolution possible

```
  private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,Camera.Parameters parameters) 
{
    Camera.Size result=null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
      if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
        if (result == null) {
          result=size;
        }
        else {
          int resultArea=result.width * result.height;
          int newArea=size.width * size.height;

          if (newArea > resultArea) {
            result=size;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return(result);
  }
```

Or stop the loop at the resolution you want.

Taken from [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Picture/src/com/commonsware/android/picture/PictureDemo.java) (commonsguy github)